# 'pkglibexecdir' is not a legitimate directory

Tags: compiling, gnu, gnu-make, automake, autotools

I'm following some outdated instructions in an attempt to compile some proprietary, closed-source, unsupported, legacy code. Here is what a typical shell session looks like:

```
$ autoreconf -fi

src/Makefile.am:7: error: 'pkglibexecdir' is not a legitimate directory for 'PYTHON'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1


$ cat src/Makefile.am

pkglibexecdir = $(libexecdir)/packagename

nobase_pkglibexec_PYTHON = \
        python_module_1.py
        python_module_2.py
        [...]

MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = Makefile.in
BUILT_SOURCES = some_source

some_source:
    ln -s ../lib/python/some_source some_source
```

I'm using GNU Autoconf version 2.69. I'm also having similar issues with other packages in the same project. I'm assuming that there's a quick fix for this problem but I'm not very comfortable with autotools and most of what I've found via google hasn't made a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a trick to circumvent `automake`'s policing. See https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Uniform.html:

> This feature can also be used to override the sanity checks Automake performs to diagnose suspicious directory/primary couples (in the unlikely case these checks are undesirable, and you really know what you’re doing). For example, Automake would error out on this input:
>
> ```
> # Forbidden directory combinations, automake will error out on this.
> pkglib_PROGRAMS = foo
> doc_LIBRARIES = libquux.a
> ```
>
> but it will succeed with this:
>
> ```
> # Work around forbidden directory combinations.  Do not use this
> # without a very good reason!
> my_execbindir = $(pkglibdir)
> my_doclibdir = $(docdir)
>
> my_execbin_PROGRAMS = foo
> my_doclib_LIBRARIES = libquux.a
> ```